# Python twisted reactor - address already in use

Tags: python, macos, sockets, twisted

I'm following a tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server for creating a sample using socket programming in Mac OS X enviromment.

I'm writing using post 80 for reactor.listenTCP(80, factory).
When I run the server.py file, getting an error:

```
File "server.py", line 10, in <module>
    reactor.listenTCP(6, factory)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 436, in listenTCP
    p.startListening()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 641, in startListening
    raise CannotListenError, (self.interface, self.port, le)
twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:80: [Errno 48] Address already in use.
```

Source code is as follow:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

If I'm using another port no like 6 etc, it is working fine.
I just wanted to know, how can I use port 80 for the same application.

Comment: Port 80 is reserverd for HTTP protocol. Check if don't have process running on this port. Maybe some HTTP server, like apache?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Open Activity Monitor, search for Python and kill the process. You probably messed up with closing a server once.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this issue too, actually, just now.

Here is what I did:

```
MacBook-Air:Desktop user$ sudo lsof -i:80
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Python  1276 root    3u  IPv4 ******      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
MacBook-Air:Desktop user$ sudo kill 1276
MacBook-Air:Desktop user$ sudo python server.py 
Iphone Chat server started
```

Then everything goes well.

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was that apache was already listening on port 80.  Seems like a lot of people google through this post and other ones with this issue but I don't see this particular answer offered.  It was what worked for me so I thought that I would add to it in case it helps:
Running Mac/Mavericks but the issue would occur on any other system where Apache runs by default ... or one might forget it's running.

Did

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:80 | grep LISTEN
```

Got

```
httpd      20 root    4u  IPv6 0x1d12a12e12345b12      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     109 _www    4u  IPv6 0x1d12a12e12345b12      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     437 _www    4u  IPv6 0x1d12a12e12345b12      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     438 _www    4u  IPv6 0x1d12a12e12345b12      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     439 _www    4u  IPv6 0x1d12a12e12345b12      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

did

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

And the server worked just fine on port 80 after that.

Comment: This finds what processes are listening.  This is the best answer IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

You can't listen port if another application already bound socket to this port. For example read [socket.bind](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind)