# CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:9008: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python-2.7, server, twisted, autobahn, autobahnws

I am working on Autobahn's app on websocket over python.
I found one problem, if I restart my server code once after interrupting then my server code will send me error like:

```
2016-03-03 13:20:34+0530 [-] Log opened.
2016-03-03 13:20:34+0530 [-] Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-03-03 13:20:34+0530 [-]   File "TestServer.py", line 23, in <module>
2016-03-03 13:20:34+0530 [-]     reactor.listenTCP(9008, factory)
2016-03-03 13:20:34+0530 [-]   File "/home/ddserver/python1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 478, in listenTCP
2016-03-03 13:20:34+0530 [-]     p.startListening()
2016-03-03 13:20:34+0530 [-]   File "/home/ddserver/python1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 984, in startListening
2016-03-03 13:20:34+0530 [-]     raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le)
2016-03-03 13:20:34+0530 [-] twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:9008: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
```

I understand by error is there are some basic services which is running on behind even after interrupting server, but how clear all such ports ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite right about that , your service keeps on running even after you interupt . You need to check for your process that is running on that port and kill it manually.
You can use the command: **ps aux** to look for your process and kill it using : **kill -9** 
Or you could find help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex):

Answer (score 3):

`sudo lsof -i TCP:9008 | grep LISTEN` works well.

Refer to [Python twisted reactor - address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640711/python-twisted-reactor-address-already-in-use)